# Add Python Code to Smartsheets For All Users

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I've developed a Python script that helps track and organize various tasks in Smartsheet but I want to assign it to a button inside of the Smartsheet such that it is available for multiple users. Is there a way to do this and could someone provide some documentation? Thus far I haven't seen anything online.

Thank you,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Smartsheet doesn't host scripts, nor does it natively have a way to execute your remote scripts. You'd need to either host it yourself or host it on a cloud platform like [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/integration-remote-scripts.html) or Azure. Inside Smartsheet, you could create a dashboard widget that then links to your own server.

Comment: Okay so I'd still need to have someone click on the script? It may be better to just setup my computer to run it every hour.

Comment: I'm a little late here, but I would recommend two options to automate your script. 1.) Use Smartsheet webhooks to trigger the script when a change occurs within a specific sheet. 2.) Use a cronjob to automatically run the script every hour. In both cases, a Serverless tool like Lambda or Azure Functions would work well and probably be free (depending on the scale).